# '>=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'int' Python Error

Tags: python

```
t = [1,2]
J = range(5)
```

y's are variables to be determined
I'm trying to make loop that looks like this:

```
1*x + y[0,0] >= 10
1*x + y[0,1] >= 10
1*x + y[0,2] >= 10
1*x + y[0,3] >= 10
1*x + y[0,4] >= 10

2*x + y[1,0] >= 10
2*x + y[1,1] >= 10
2*x + y[1,2] >= 10
2*x + y[1,3] >= 10
2*x + y[1,4] >= 10
```

but when I try to make this as a loop: for example, like this

```
for i in range(t):
    (t[i]*x + y[i,j] for j in J) >= 10
```

it gives me an error saying that

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'int'
```

I am wondering why I get this error. When I type the indexes for each t, and type in loop indexes for y, it doesn't give me any error but when I loop it, it gives me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with these 10 comparisons?

Comment: That is not a loop, that is a generator expression which creates a generator object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're asking. I *think* you want a list of booleans that show if the calculation is greater than or equal to 10 for each of the items in your original list. If so, you need to do that comparison within the loop, for each item, rather than for the loop as a whole. Perhaps:

```
(t[i]*x + y[i,j] >= 10 for j in J)
```

However I can't see what you're actually doing with that generator, so I'm not sure this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
T = [1,2]
J = range(5)
models = [(t*x) + y[i,j] >= 10 for j in J for i, t in enumerate(T)]
```

which will give you a list of 10 `True`s and/or `False`s, named `models`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a for loop, use NUMPY!

`(t[i]*x + y[i,j] for j in J)` is a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). You're also not doing anything with this comparison, you're just throwing it into the void.

But note this is `numpy` (I assume, since you're doing `y[i, j]`). If you're using a `for` loop you're probably doing something wrong. Instead use numpy as it was designed... with array operations!

```
t = np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis]
comparison = (t*x + y) >= 10
```

ta-da brand new boolean array. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

x = 1.5
y = np.random.randint(0, 16, (2, 5))
t = np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis]

new = t*x + y
comparison = new >= 10

print(f'x = {x},\ny = \n{y},\n\nt = \n{t},\n\nnew = \n{new},\n\ncomp = \n{comparison}')
```

Which outputs

```
x = 1.5,
y = 
[[10 14 12  5  3]
 [15  9  2  1 13]],

t = 
[[0]
 [1]],

new = 
[[ 10.   14.   12.    5.    3. ]
 [ 16.5  10.5   3.5   2.5  14.5]],

comp = 
[[ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False  True]]
```